# cannot implicity convert type localhost.Coin to Coin

Tags: c#, web-services, localhost

im trying to learn about web service so im new on it, im trying to send an object throw web service, the name of the object is coin.
i tried to put the class in both my site and the site with the webservice, i know its not what i should do but im just trying to make it work and it still not working, this message always apear "cannot implicity convert type localhost.Coin to Coin". how can i send an object without this problem?
the name of the method is transferCoin and it gets a string, i tried many ways and this is one of them:

```
Coin c = new Coin();
WebService w = new WebService();
c=w.transferCoin(ListBox1.SelectedValue);
```

what to do?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much looks like you have two different definitions of Coin(). That is what the exception tells you. Considering your remarks, you've perhaps added the Coin() object twice; one time in the client/website and once in the service?

To verify this assumption, try if the following works:

```cs
// [comment this] Coin c = new Coin();
WebService w = new WebService();
var c = w.transferCoin(ListBox1.SelectedValue);
```

Here, you do not use the Coin object, as defined on your site. But more the object as defined in the service.

Comment: ty vary much you are right i had the same object in both of the sites, im sorry for not noticing.
but why cant i use the functions from the class? c. wont show the functions i built in there.

Comment: A webservice can only used to communicate requests and responses, e.g. only values/properties. It cannot send implementations of a class like functions "over the line". If you implement a service pattern well, you should have no further need for any functions on your Coin() object, which should be provided by your webservice. However, there are reasonable scenarios where you could want this. In this case, your best bet would be to create a seperate Class Library as a new project, define the Coin() class there, and reference this new project from both your website as well as your service.